# Normalized weighted Euclidian Distance

Tags: mathematical-statistics, euclidean

Hi Guys I would like to get an euclidian distance and be able to compare multiple set o data but I am not sure how to normalized it properly 
Each data set have values ranging from (-100->100) and with weight from (0-> 5)

I give you an example( I use python to calculate it):

```
def test2(x, y, z):
    return sqrt(sum(c*(pow(a-b, 2)) for a, b, c in zip(x, y, z)))

c = test2([90,-74,83],[57,83,-72],[1,4,3])
```

with a output distance of 414.4393803682271

I would like to translate that value on a scale from 0-100 how can I do it ?

Thx you very much

Answer (score 2):

For example, if  $x $ is your Euclidean distance, then normalized value could be equal to $ N(x)=\frac{100x}{1 + x} $. (While $x$ goes from 0 to $ +\infty$, $N(x)$ goes from 0 to 100.)

There are many different functions -- we could give a more thorough answer if you would come up with some domain-specific constraints on normalizing function. (For example, you could consider [sigmoid functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function).)